# Merging DataTables in vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datatable

I use vb.net to develop and I've used 5 DataTables in a windows application form and I need to combine these 5 DataTables together base on a primary key field.

To clarify

```
DataTable1 (PK,f1,f2,f3)
DataTable2 (PK,f4,f5,f6)
DataTable3 (PK,f7)
DataTable4 (PK,f8)
DataTable5 (PK,f9)
```

I need to have :

```
DataTable (pk,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9 )
```

Comment: I used DataTable.Merge but this adds additional rows for second table. it does not match the ids and maintains the row count

Comment: You should look into using a `Dataset`, then join all of the tables on the primary key when you select.  I think you can do this with a `Dataview`, though I've only used that class on a single table.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` to your project,

Then you can perform a UNION on the tables like this:

```
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim dt2 As DataTable

    Dim result = dt.AsEnumerable().Union(dt2.AsEnumerable())
```